# Creating a selection of objects from an array of objects based on a third flat array

Tags: arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects called `allData`, and a selection of IDs of these objects as a flat array called `selection`.

I need to create a third array called `selectionWithNames` that will be identical to `allData`, except it should contain only the objects whose IDs are in `selection`.

I know how to filter based on one value, but I'm not sure how to do it based on an array. Any idea?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLrybqhv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I know how to filter based on one value, but I'm not sure how to do it based on an array."

Well in essence, you will be doing the exact same check, but instead of checking each items vs a value, you will check an items existence within your other array, like so:

```
const selectionWithNames = allData.filter((i) => selection.includes(i.id) );
```

Check more on includes and other basic array functions [here!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)